# jquery fade-in on page load works in all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used the following script to fade-in an image when the page loads:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('img').load(function() {         
            $(this).fadeIn(4000);     
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

The css is set to display none.

This works in all the major browsers, but not in IE. In IE, the image is just not displayed at all. How can I get the fade-in to work in IE?

Comment: Please provide IE version

Answer (score 0):

IE seems to have issues with fading in and out (see [reference](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/)). You can write a little custom function to handle this:

EDIT: I simplified the code to the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').fadeIn(4000, function (){
        $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work in IE - just the other browsers. Could the problem be in the CSS? My CSS for img is:
 display: none;
 
}

Comment: it works for my IE, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using version 10.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the revised code. Again, the image just does not appear at all in IE. In the other browsers, the image fades in when the page loads, like it is supposed to do. Any more ideas?

Comment: Is javascript enabled in your IE browser?

Comment: I have discovered that the problem is in the load function with IE. IE puts the image in a cache. The first time, the function works and the image fades in on page load. Them IE puts the image in the cache and when the page is refreshed, the image does not show at all because IE only sees: display:none. Any thoughts on how to get IE not to cache the image?

Comment: I updated my answer. Instead of preventing the image from being cached, I realized you don't even need the `onload` event handler.